# new style formating in python with dictionaries

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm learning python and I don't understand something about the 'new style' of formatting. Here is my code:

```
>>> d={'n':32,'f':5.03,'s':'test string'}
>>> '{0[n]} {0[f]} {0[s]} {1}'.format(d, 'other')
'32 5.03 test string other'
```

but when I type in the console:

```
>>> d[n]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
>>> d['n']
32
```

So why in the formatted string, 0[n] without quotes was able to read from the dictionary the value with the key 'n' (in this case the key is a string) but when I've tried this in the console, it didn't worked.

Also, what would happen if the key is not a string?

Thanks

Comment: did you try out what happens with non-string key? not that hard to do... it works f.e. with integers

Comment: I would like to understand what happens under the hood...

Comment: beside that ... that is _not_ new style formatting ... that would the stringinterpolation (f-strings)

Comment: well, in the book that I'm reading, there are presented two way of formatting string and this interpolation is presented as the new style of formatting... as I said, now I'm learning it

Comment: your book is ooooold ;)  you can use`print(f"{d['n']} {d['f']} {d['s']} other")` and read this [pep 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) or read up on all methods (f.-string, format, %s) here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Comment: @PatrickArtner https://imgur.com/a/dnPld3r this is from the book that I'm reading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'{0[n]}...'` is a string that is interpreted by the method `format()`. The Python parser does not care about the content of that string, and `format` can use any notation, regardless of what is valid in Python and what is not.

`O[n]` is not a string, it is a Python expression. When Python parses it, it attempts to resolve `n` as a variable, which, in your case, does not exist. Your attempt would work if you executed `n='n'` before the lookup.

Comment: and in the expression '{0[n]}...' how is n interpreted? because this is not clear to me...

Comment: It is interpreted by the method `format` as `O["n"]`.